# How to remove a lot of the duplication in this JavaScript AST transformer?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have put together [this complete runnable source code](https://github.com/lancejpollard/normalize-ast.js/blob/make/index.js) with an example set of [test expressions](https://github.com/lancejpollard/normalize-ast.js/blob/make/test.js) which it parses and prints. The code requires `acorn`, which is a JS AST generator from a string, so it can't easily run in StackOverflow I don't think. But here is the main [index.js](https://github.com/lancejpollard/normalize-ast.js/blob/1a44a0be767015fafebccd4e0ef7efc9aba85785/index.js) which I would like to refactor:

```
const acorn = require('acorn')
const print = require('./print')
const {
  createMemberExpression,
  createConditionalExpression,
  createBinaryExpression,
  createLogicalExpression,
  createIdentifier,
  createLiteral,
  createExpressionStatement,
  createVariableDeclaration,
  createVariableDeclarator,
  createAssignmentExpression,
  createCallExpression,
  createFunctionDeclaration,
  createFunctionExpression,
  createArrowFunctionExpression,
  createAssignmentPattern,
  createReturnStatement,
  createIfStatement,
  createBlockStatement,
  createObjectExpression,
  createProperty,
  createArrayExpression,
  createForInStatement,
  createForOfStatement,
  createWhileStatement,
  createLabeledStatement
} = require('./create')

module.exports = {
  parse,
  print,
  normalize
}

function parse(string) {
  return acorn.parse(string, { ecmaVersion: 2021, sourceType: 'module' })
}

function normalize(input) {
  const output = {
    type: 'Program',
    body: []
  }
  const scope = {
    index: 0,
  }

  input.body.forEach(node => {
    output.body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(node, scope))
  })

  return output
}

function normalizeBodyNode(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const normalizers = {
    VariableDeclaration() {
      const declarations = normalizeVariableDeclaration(node, scope)
      output.push(...declarations)
    },

    ExpressionStatement() {
      const expressions = normalizeExpressionStatement(node.expression, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
    },

    FunctionDeclaration() {
      output.push(...normalizeFunctionDeclaration(node, scope))
    },

    ReturnStatement() {
      output.push(...normalizeReturnStatement(node, scope))
    },

    IfStatement() {
      const [ifStatement, expressions] = normalizeIfStatement(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(ifStatement)
    },

    SwitchStatement() {
      const [swtch, expressions] = normalizeSwitchStatement(node, scope)
    },

    ForInStatement() {
      const [forInStatement, expressions] = normalizeForInStatement(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(forInStatement)
    },

    ForOfStatement() {
      const [forOfStatement, expressions] = normalizeForOfStatement(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(forOfStatement)
    },

    WhileStatement() {
      const [whileStatement, expressions] = normalizeWhileStatement(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(whileStatement)
    },

    ClassDeclaration() {
      const [clss, expressions] = normalizeClassDeclaration(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(clss)
    },

    BreakStatement() {
      output.push(node)
    },

    LabeledStatement() {
      const [body] = normalizeBodyNode(node.body, scope)
      const [label] = normalizeExpression(node.label, scope)
      output.push(createLabeledStatement(label, body))
    },

    ForStatement() {
      const blockStatement = normalizeForStatement(node, scope)
      output.push(blockStatement)
    },

    BlockStatement() {
      output.push(normalizeBlockStatement(node, scope))
    },

    AssignmentExpression() {
      const [assign, expressions] = normalizeAssignmentExpression(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(assign)
    },

    ExportNamedDeclaration() {
      const [exp, expressions] = normalizeExportNamedDeclaration(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(exp)
    }
  }

  call(normalizers, node.type)
  return output
}

function normalizeExportNamedDeclaration(node, scope) {
  const declaration = normalizeBodyNode(node.declaration, scope)
  const specifiers = []
}

function normalizeAssignmentExpression(node, scope) {
  const [left, leftExps] = normalizeExpression(node.left, scope)
  const [right, rightExps] = normalizeExpression(node.right, scope)
  return [
    createAssignmentExpression(left, right, node.operator),
    [...leftExps, ...rightExps]
  ]
}

function normalizeBlockStatement(node, scope) {
  const childScope = { ...scope }
  const body = []
  node.body.forEach(bd => {
    body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(bd, childScope))
  })
  return createBlockStatement(body)
}

function normalizeForStatement(node, scope) {
  const childScope = { ...scope }
  let initExps
  if (node.init) {
    initExps = normalizeBodyNode(node.init, childScope)
  } else {
    initExps = []
  }
  let test, testExps = []
  if (node.test) {
    [test, testExps] = normalizeExpression(node.test, childScope, true)
  }
  const [update, updateExps] = normalizeExpression(node.update, childScope)
  const body = []
  const normalizers = {
    BlockStatement() {
      node.body.body.forEach(bd => {
        body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(bd, childScope))
      })
    },

    ExpressionStatement() {
      body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(node.body, childScope))
    }
  }
  call(normalizers, node.body.type)
  const block = createBlockStatement([
    ...initExps,
    createWhileStatement(
      createLiteral(true),
      [
        ...testExps,
        createIfStatement(test,
          createBlockStatement([
            ...body,
            ...updateExps,
            update
          ]),
          createBlockStatement([
            createBreakStatement()
          ])
        )
      ]
    )
  ])
  return block
}

function normalizeClassDeclaration(node, scope) {
  const [id, idExps] = normalizeExpression(node.id, scope)
  const output = [...idExps]
  const superClass = null
  const [body, bodyExps] = normalizeClassBody(node.body, scope)
  output.push(...bodyExps)
  return [createClassDeclaration(id, superClass, body), output]
}

function createClassDeclaration(id, superClass, body) {
  return {
    type: 'ClassDeclaration',
    id,
    superClass,
    body
  }
}

function normalizeClassBody(node, scope) {
  const body = []
  const output = []
  node.body.forEach(bd => {
    const [method, methodExps] = normalizeMethodDefinition(bd, scope)
    output.push(...methodExps)
    body.push(method)
  })
  return [createClassBody(body), output]
}

function createClassBody(body) {
  return {
    type: 'ClassBody',
    body
  }
}

function normalizeMethodDefinition(node, scope) {
  const [key, keyExps] = normalizeExpression(node.key, scope)
  const value = normalizeFunctionExpression(node.value, scope)
  return [createMethodDefinition(key, value.pop()), keyExps]
}

function createMethodDefinition(key, value) {
  return {
    type: 'MethodDefinition',
    key,
    value
  }
}

function normalizeForInStatement(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const [left, leftExps] = normalizeExpression(node.left, scope)
  const [right, rightExps] = normalizeExpression(node.right, scope)
  output.push(...leftExps)
  output.push(...rightExps)
  const body = []
  if (node.body.type === 'BlockStatement') {
    node.body.body.forEach(bd => {
      body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(bd, { ...scope }))
    })
  } else {
    body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(node.body, { ...scope }))
  }
  const forInStatement = createForInStatement(left, right, body)
  return [forInStatement, output]
}

function normalizeForOfStatement(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const [left, leftExps] = normalizeExpression(node.left, scope)
  const [right, rightExps] = normalizeExpression(node.right, scope)
  output.push(...leftExps)
  output.push(...rightExps)
  const body = []
  node.body.body.forEach(bd => {
    body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(bd, { ...scope }))
  })
  const forOfStatement = createForOfStatement(left, right, body)
  return [forOfStatement, output]
}

function createBreakStatement(label) {
  return {
    type: 'BreakStatement',
    label
  }
}

function normalizeWhileStatement(node, scope) {
  const [test, testExps] = normalizeExpression(node.test, scope, true)
  const body = []
  node.body.body.forEach(bd => {
    body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(bd, { ...scope }))
  })
  const newBody = [...testExps, createIfStatement(test, createBlockStatement(body), createBlockStatement([createBreakStatement()]))]
  const whileStatement = createWhileStatement(createLiteral(true), newBody)
  return [whileStatement, []]
}

function normalizeSwitchStatement(node, scope) {
  const discriminant = normalizeExpression(node.discriminant)
  return []
}

function normalizeIfStatement(node, scope) {
  const top = []
  const [test, testExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.test, scope, true)
  top.push(...testExpressionStatements)
  let consequent = []
  if (node.consequent.type === 'BlockStatement') {
    node.consequent.body.forEach(statement => {
      const cons = normalizeBodyNode(statement, { ...scope })
      consequent.push(...cons)
    })
  } else {
    consequent.push(...normalizeExpressionStatement(node.consequent, { ...scope }))
  }
  consequent = createBlockStatement(consequent)
  let alternate = null
  if (node.alternate) {
    if (node.alternate.type === 'BlockStatement') {
      alternate = []
      node.alternate.body.forEach(statement => {
        const alts = normalizeBodyNode(statement, { ...scope })
        alternate.push(...alts)
      })
      alternate = createBlockStatement(alternate)
    } else {
      [alternate, altExpressionStatements] = normalizeIfStatement(node.alternate, scope)
      top.push(...altExpressionStatements)
    }
  }

  const ifStatement = createIfStatement(test, consequent, alternate)
  return [ifStatement, top]
}

function normalizeReturnStatement(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const [arg, expressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.argument, scope, true)
  output.push(...expressionStatements)
  output.push(createReturnStatement(arg))
  return output
}

function normalizeArrowFunctionExpression(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const params = []
  node.params.forEach(param => {
    const [p, pExpressionStatements] = normalizeFunctionParam(param, scope)
    output.push(...pExpressionStatements)
    params.push(p)
  })
  const normalizers = {
    CallExpression() {
      [body, expressions] = normalizeExpression(node.body, { ...scope }, true);
      body = createBlockStatement([
        ...expressions,
        body
      ])
    },

    ArrayExpression() {
      [body, expressions] = normalizeExpression(node.body, { ...scope });
      body = createBlockStatement([
        ...expressions,
        createReturnStatement(body),
      ])
    },

    ObjectExpression() {
      [body, expressions] = normalizeExpression(node.body, { ...scope });
      body = createBlockStatement([
        ...expressions,
        createReturnStatement(body),
      ])
    },

    BlockStatement() {
      body = []
      const childScope = { ...scope }
      node.body.body.forEach(bd => {
        body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(bd, childScope))
      })
      body = createBlockStatement(body)
    },

    BinaryExpression() {
      [body, expressions] = normalizeExpression(node.body, { ...scope });
      body = createBlockStatement([
        ...expressions,
        createReturnStatement(body),
      ])
    }
  }
  let body
  call(normalizers, node.body.type)
  return [
    createArrowFunctionExpression(node.id, params, body),
    output
  ]
}

function normalizeFunctionExpression(node, scope) {
  const childScope = { ...scope }
  const output = []
  const params = []
  node.params.forEach(param => {
    const [p, pExpressionStatements] = normalizeFunctionParam(param, childScope)
    output.push(...pExpressionStatements)
    params.push(p)
  })
  const body = []
  node.body.body.forEach(bd => {
    body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(bd, childScope))
  })
  output.push(createFunctionExpression(node.id, params, body))
  return output
}

function normalizeFunctionDeclaration(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const params = []
  node.params.forEach(param => {
    const [p, pExpressionStatements] = normalizeFunctionParam(param, scope)
    output.push(...pExpressionStatements)
    params.push(p)
  })
  const body = []
  node.body.body.forEach(bd => {
    body.push(...normalizeBodyNode(bd, scope))
  })
  output.push(createFunctionDeclaration(node.id, params, body))
  return output
}

function normalizeFunctionParam(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const expressionStatements = []
  const normalizers = {
    Identifier() {
      output.push(node)
    },

    AssignmentPattern() {
      const [left] = normalizeExpression(node.left, scope)
      const [right, rightExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.right, scope)
      expressionStatements.push(...rightExpressionStatements)
      // TODO: do inside the function.
      output.push(
        createAssignmentPattern(left, right)
      )
    },

    RestElement() {
      const [rest, restExps] = normalizeRestElement(node, scope)
      expressionStatements.push(...restExps)
      output.push(rest)
    }
  }
  call(normalizers, node.type)
  output.push(expressionStatements)
  return output
}

function normalizeRestElement(node, scope) {
  const [arg, argExps] = normalizeExpression(node.argument, scope)
  return [
    createRestElement(arg),
    argExps
  ]
}

function createRestElement(argument) {
  return {
    type: 'RestElement',
    argument
  }
}

function normalizeVariableDeclaration(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  node.declarations.forEach(dec => {
    const declarations = normalizeVariableDeclarator(node, dec, scope)
    output.push(...declarations)
  })
  return output
}

function normalizeVariableDeclarator(parent, node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const normalizeId = {
    Identifier() {
      const normalizeInit = {
        Identifier() {
          output.push(
            createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
              createVariableDeclarator(node.id, node.init)
            ])
          )
        },

        Literal() {
          output.push(
            createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
              createVariableDeclarator(node.id, node.init)
            ])
          )
        },

        ObjectExpression() {
          const props = []
          node.init.properties.forEach(prop => {
            const [p, pExpressionStatements] = normalizeProperty(prop, scope)
            props.push(p)
            output.push(...pExpressionStatements)
          })
          output.push(createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
            createVariableDeclarator(node.id,
              createObjectExpression(props)
            )
          ]))
        },

        ArrayExpression() {
          const els = []
          node.init.elements.forEach(element => {
            const [p, pExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(element, scope)
            els.push(p)
            output.push(...pExpressionStatements)
          })
          output.push(createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
            createVariableDeclarator(node.id,
              createArrayExpression(els)
            )
          ]))
        },

        ConditionalExpression() {
          const [test, testExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.test, scope)
          const [consequent, consequentExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.consequent, scope)
          const [alternate, alternateExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.alternate, scope)
          output.push(...testExpressionStatements)
          output.push(...consequentExpressionStatements)
          output.push(...alternateExpressionStatements)
          output.push(createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
            createVariableDeclarator(node.id,
              createConditionalExpression(
                test,
                consequent,
                alternate
              )
            )
          ]))
        },

        FunctionExpression() {
          // output.push(...normalizeFunctionExpression(node.init, { ...scope }))
        },

        MemberExpression() {
          const [object, objectStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.object, scope)
          const [property, propertyStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.property, scope)
          output.push(...objectStatements)
          output.push(...propertyStatements)
          output.push(createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
            createVariableDeclarator(node.id,
              createMemberExpression(
                object,
                property,
                node.init.computed
              )
            )
          ]))
        },

        BinaryExpression() {
          const [left, leftExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.left, scope, true)
          const [right, rightExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.right, scope, true)
          output.push(...leftExpressionStatements)
          output.push(...rightExpressionStatements)
          output.push(createVariable(parent.kind, node.id, createBinaryExpression(
            left,
            node.init.operator,
            right
          )))
        },

        ArrowFunctionExpression() {
          const [func, expressions] = normalizeArrowFunctionExpression(node.init, scope)
          output.push(...expressions)
          output.push(createVariable(parent.kind, node.id, func))
        },

        NewExpression() {
          const [ctor, expressions] = normalizeNewExpression(node.init, scope)
          output.push(...expressions)
          output.push(createVariable(parent.kind, node.id, ctor))
        },

        CallExpression() {
          const [_callee, calleeStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.callee, scope)
          const args = []
          node.init.arguments.forEach(arg => {
            const [argument, argumentStatements] = normalizeExpression(arg, scope, true)
            output.push(...argumentStatements)
            args.push(argument)
          })
          output.push(...calleeStatements)
          output.push(createVariable(parent.kind, node.id,
            createCallExpression(_callee, args)
          ))
        },

        TemplateLiteral() {
          const [template, expressions] = normalizeTemplateLiteral(node.init, scope)
          output.push(...expressions)
          output.push(createVariable(parent.kind, node.id, template))
        },

        TaggedTemplateExpression() {
          const [template, expressions] = normalizeTaggedTemplateExpression(node.init, scope)
          output.push(...expressions)
          output.push(createVariable(parent.kind, node.id, template))
        },

        UnaryExpression() {
          const [update, updateExps] = normalizeUnaryExpression(node.init, scope, true)
          output.push(...updateExps)
          // if (isolate) {
          //   const name = `tmp${scope.index++}`
          //   output.push(
          //     createVariable('const',
          //       createIdentifier(name),
          //       update
          //     )
          //   )
          //   output.push(createVariable(parent.kind, node.id, createIdentifier(name)))
          // } else {
            output.push(createVariable(parent.kind, node.id, update))
          // }
        }
      }

      if (node.init) {
        call(normalizeInit, node.init.type)
      } else {
        output.push(createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
          createVariableDeclarator(node.id)
        ]))
      }
    },

    ObjectPattern() {
      throw new Error('todo')
    },

    ArrayPattern() {
      const normalizeInit = {
        Identifier() {
          node.id.elements.forEach(el => {
            output.push(
              createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
                createVariableDeclarator(el,
                  createMemberExpression(node.init, el))
              ])
            )
          })
        },

        MemberExpression() {
          node.id.elements.forEach(el => {
            output.push(
              createVariableDeclaration(parent.kind, [
                createVariableDeclarator(el,
                  createMemberExpression(node.init, el))
              ])
            )
          })
        },

        // CallExpression() {
        //   const [_callee, calleeStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.init.callee, scope)
        //   const args = []
        //   node.init.arguments.forEach(arg => {
        //     const [argument, argumentStatements] = normalizeExpression(arg, scope)
        //     output.push(...argumentStatements)
        //     args.push(argument)
        //   })
        //   output.push(...calleeStatements)
        //   output.push(createVariable(parent.kind,
        //     createCallExpression(_callee, args)
        //   ))
        // },
      }

      call(normalizeInit, node.init.type)
    }
  }

  call(normalizeId, node.id.type)

  return output
}

function normalizeTaggedTemplateExpression(node, scope) {
  const [tag, tagExps] = normalizeExpression(node.tag, scope)
  const [template, templateExps] = normalizeTemplateLiteral(node.quasi, scope)
  return [
    createTaggedTemplateExpression(tag, template),
    [...templateExps, ...tagExps]
  ]
}

function createTaggedTemplateExpression(tag, quasi) {
  return {
    type: 'TaggedTemplateExpression',
    tag,
    quasi
  }
}

function normalizeTemplateLiteral(node, scope) {
  const quasis = []
  const expressions = []
  const exps = []
  node.expressions.forEach(expression => {
    const [exp, expExps] = normalizeExpression(expression, scope)
    expressions.push(exp)
    exps.push(...expExps)
  })
  node.quasis.forEach(q => {
    quasis.push(normalizeTemplateElement(q, scope))
  })
  return [
    createTemplateLiteral(expressions, quasis),
    exps
  ]
}

function normalizeTemplateElement(node, scope) {
  return node
}

function createTemplateLiteral(expressions, quasis) {
  return {
    type: 'TemplateLiteral',
    expressions,
    quasis
  }
}

function createVariable(kind, id, init) {
  return createVariableDeclaration(kind, [
    createVariableDeclarator(id, init)
  ])
}

function normalizeNewExpression(node, scope) {
  const [ctor, ctorExps] = normalizeExpression(node.callee, scope)
  const argExps = []
  const args = []
  node.arguments.forEach(arg => {
    const [argument, argumentExps] = normalizeExpression(arg, { ...scope }, true)
    args.push(argument)
    argExps.push(...argumentExps)
  })
  return [createNewExpression(ctor, args), ctorExps.concat(argExps)]
}

function createNewExpression(ctor, args) {
  return {
    type: 'NewExpression',
    callee: ctor,
    arguments: args
  }
}

function normalizeSpreadElement(node, scope) {
  const [arg, argExps] = normalizeExpression(node.argument, scope)
  return [
    createSpreadElement(arg),
    argExps
  ]
}

function createSpreadElement(argument) {
  return {
    type: 'SpreadElement',
    argument
  }
}

function normalizeProperty(node, scope) {
  if (node.type === 'SpreadElement') {
    return normalizeSpreadElement(node, scope)
  }
  const output = []
  const [key, keyExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.key, scope)
  const [value, valueExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.value, scope)
  output.push(...keyExpressionStatements)
  output.push(...valueExpressionStatements)
  return [createProperty(key, value), output]
}

function normalizeExpressionStatement(node, scope) {
  const output = []
  const normalizers = {
    AssignmentExpression() {
      // if node.left.type === 'ArrayPattern'
      const [left, leftExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.left, scope)
      const [right, rightExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.right, scope)
      output.push(...leftExpressionStatements)
      output.push(...rightExpressionStatements)
      if (Array.isArray(left)) {
        const name = `tmp${scope.index++}`
        output.push(createExpressionStatement(
          createAssignmentExpression(
            createIdentifier(name),
            right
          )
        ))
        left.forEach(l => {
          output.push(createExpressionStatement(
            createAssignmentExpression(l,
              createMemberExpression(
                createIdentifier(name), l))
          ))
        })
      } else {
        output.push(createExpressionStatement(
          createAssignmentExpression(left, right)
        ))
      }
    },

    Identifier() {
      output.push(createExpressionStatement(node))
    },

    MemberExpression() {
      const [object, objectStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.object, scope)
      const [property, propertyStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.property, scope)
      output.push(...objectStatements)
      output.push(...propertyStatements)
      output.push(createExpressionStatement(
        createMemberExpression(
          object,
          property,
          node.computed
        ))
      )
    },

    CallExpression() {
      const [_callee, calleeStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.callee, scope)
      const args = []
      node.arguments.forEach(arg => {
        const [argument, argumentStatements] = normalizeExpression(arg, scope, true)
        output.push(...argumentStatements)
        args.push(argument)
      })
      output.push(...calleeStatements)
      output.push(createExpressionStatement(
        createCallExpression(_callee, args)
      ))
    },

    FunctionExpression() {
      output.push(...normalizeFunctionExpression(node, { ...scope }))
    },

    NewExpression() {
      const [ctor, expressions] = normalizeNewExpression(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(createExpressionStatement(ctor))
    },

    TaggedTemplateExpression() {
      const [template, expressions] = normalizeTaggedTemplateExpression(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(createExpressionStatement(template))
    },

    SequenceExpression() {
      const expressions = normalizeSequenceExpression(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
    },

    ReturnStatement() {
      output.push(...normalizeReturnStatement(node, scope))
    },

    Literal() {
      output.push(node)
    },

    ThrowStatement() {
      const [thrw, expressions] = normalizeThrowStatement(node, scope)
      output.push(...expressions)
      output.push(createExpressionStatement(thrw))
    }
  }
  call(normalizers, node.type)
  return output
}

function normalizeThrowStatement(node, scope) {
  const [argument, argumentExps] = normalizeExpression(node.argument, scope)
  return [
    createThrowStatement(argument),
    argumentExps
  ]
}

function createThrowStatement(argument) {
  return {
    type: 'ThrowStatement',
    argument
  }
}

function normalizeSequenceExpression(node, scope) {
  const expressions = []
  // this just flattens the list and gets rid of the node type
  // in the normalized output
  node.expressions.forEach(exp => {
    expressions.push(...normalizeExpressionStatement(exp, scope))
  })
  return expressions
}

function normalizeExpression(node, scope, isolate = false) {
  const expressionStatements = []
  const output = []
  const normalizers = {
    Identifier() {
      output.push(node)
    },

    MemberExpression() {
      const [object, objectStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.object, scope, isolate)
      const [property, propertyStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.property, scope, isolate)
      expressionStatements.push(...objectStatements)
      expressionStatements.push(...propertyStatements)
      output.push(createMemberExpression(
        object,
        property,
        node.computed
      ))
    },

    CallExpression() {
      const [_callee, calleeStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.callee, scope, isolate)
      const args = []
      node.arguments.forEach(arg => {
        const [argument, argumentStatements] = normalizeExpression(arg, scope, true)
        expressionStatements.push(...argumentStatements)
        args.push(argument)
      })
      expressionStatements.push(...calleeStatements)
      const name = `tmp${scope.index++}`
      output.push(createIdentifier(name))
      expressionStatements.push(
        createVariableDeclaration('const', [
          createVariableDeclarator(
            createIdentifier(name),
            createCallExpression(_callee, args)
          )
        ])
      )
    },

    LogicalExpression() {
      const [left, leftExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.left, scope, true)
      const [right, rightExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.right, scope, true)
      expressionStatements.push(...leftExpressionStatements)
      expressionStatements.push(...rightExpressionStatements)
      const logicalExp = createLogicalExpression(
        left,
        node.operator,
        right
      )
      if (isolate) {
        const name = `tmp${scope.index++}`
        expressionStatements.push(
          createVariable('const',
            createIdentifier(name),
            logicalExp
          )
        )
        output.push(createIdentifier(name))
      } else {
        output.push(logicalExp)
      }
    },

    BinaryExpression() {
      const [left, leftExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.left, scope, true)
      const [right, rightExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.right, scope, true)
      expressionStatements.push(...leftExpressionStatements)
      expressionStatements.push(...rightExpressionStatements)
      const binary = createBinaryExpression(
        left,
        node.operator,
        right
      )
      if (isolate) {
        const name = `tmp${scope.index++}`
        expressionStatements.push(
          createVariable('const',
            createIdentifier(name),
            binary
          )
        )
        output.push(createIdentifier(name))
      } else {
        output.push(binary)
      }
    },

    ConditionalExpression() {
      const [test, testExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.test, scope, true)
      const [consequent, consequentExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.consequent, scope, true)
      const [alternate, alternateExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(node.alternate, scope, true)
      expressionStatements.push(...testExpressionStatements)
      expressionStatements.push(...consequentExpressionStatements)
      expressionStatements.push(...alternateExpressionStatements)
      const conditional = createConditionalExpression(
        test,
        consequent,
        alternate
      )
      if (isolate) {
        const name = `tmp${scope.index++}`
        expressionStatements.push(
          createVariable('const',
            createIdentifier(name),
            conditional
          )
        )
        output.push(createIdentifier(name))
      } else {
        output.push(conditional)
      }
    },

    AssignmentExpression() {
      const [assign, expressions] = normalizeAssignmentExpression(node, scope)
      expressionStatements.push(...expressions)
      output.push(assign)
    },

    ArrayPattern() {
      const array = []
      node.elements.forEach(element => {
        const [el, elExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(element, scope)
        array.push(el)
        expressionStatements.push(...elExpressionStatements)
      })
      output.push(array)
    },

    Literal() {
      output.push(node)
    },

    ObjectExpression() {
      const array = []
      node.properties.forEach(prop => {
        const [el, elExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(prop, scope)
        array.push(el)
        expressionStatements.push(...elExpressionStatements)
      })
      const objectExp = createObjectExpression(array)
      if (isolate) {
        const name = `tmp${scope.index++}`
        expressionStatements.push(
          createVariable('const',
            createIdentifier(name),
            objectExp
          )
        )
        output.push(createIdentifier(name))
      } else {
        output.push(objectExp)
      }
    },

    Property() {
      const [key, keyExps] = normalizeExpression(node.key, scope)
      const [value, valueExps] = normalizeExpression(node.value, scope)
      expressionStatements.push(...keyExps)
      expressionStatements.push(...valueExps)
      output.push(createProperty(key, value))
    },

    ArrayExpression() {
      const array = []
      node.elements.forEach(element => {
        const [el, elExpressionStatements] = normalizeExpression(element, scope)
        array.push(el)
        expressionStatements.push(...elExpressionStatements)
      })
      output.push(createArrayExpression(array))
    },

    FunctionExpression() {
      output.push(...normalizeFunctionExpression(node, scope))
    },

    VariableDeclaration() {
      output.push(...normalizeVariableDeclaration(node, scope))
    },

    ThisExpression() {
      output.push(node)
    },

    SpreadElement() {
      const [spread, expressions] = normalizeSpreadElement(node, scope)
      expressionStatements.push(...expressions)
      output.push(spread)
    },

    ArrowFunctionExpression() {
      const [arrow, arrowExps] = normalizeArrowFunctionExpression(node, scope)
      expressionStatements.push(...arrowExps)
      output.push(arrow)
    },

    UpdateExpression() {
      const [update, updateExps] = normalizeUpdateExpression(node, scope)
      expressionStatements.push(...updateExps)
      output.push(update)
    },

    UnaryExpression() {
      const [update, updateExps] = normalizeUnaryExpression(node, scope, isolate)
      expressionStatements.push(...updateExps)
      if (isolate) {
        const name = `tmp${scope.index++}`
        expressionStatements.push(
          createVariable('const',
            createIdentifier(name),
            update
          )
        )
        output.push(createIdentifier(name))
      } else {
        output.push(update)
      }
    },

    NewExpression() {
      const [ctor, expressions] = normalizeNewExpression(node, scope)
      expressionStatements.push(...expressions)
      output.push(ctor)
    }
  }

  call(normalizers, node.type)
  output.push(expressionStatements)
  return output
}

function normalizeUnaryExpression(node, scope, isolate) {
  const [argument, argumentExps] = normalizeExpression(node.argument, scope, isolate)
  return [
    createUnaryExpression(argument, node.operator, node.prefix),
    argumentExps
  ]
}

function createUnaryExpression(argument, operator, prefix) {
  return {
    type: 'UnaryExpression',
    argument,
    operator,
    prefix
  }
}

function normalizeUpdateExpression(node, scope) {
  const [argument, argumentExps] = normalizeExpression(node.argument, scope)
  return [
    createUpdateExpression(argument, node.operator, node.prefix),
    argumentExps
  ]
}

function createUpdateExpression(argument, operator, prefix) {
  return {
    type: 'UpdateExpression',
    argument,
    operator,
    prefix
  }
}

function call(obj, method, ...args) {
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
    throw new Error(`Missing method ${method}`)
  }

  return obj[method](...args)
}
```

So what this does is take a JavaScript source string, parse it into an AST, the traverse the AST and "normalize" it in a certain way, essentially hoisting variables and putting everything on a single line, so there are no nested expressions really. I am doing this for a side project, to transpile JS into a custom programming language, which only has rudimentary structures. So I simplify/normalize the JS so it can be easily converted into the target language.

The way the code above works is, it is at a certain node. Then within that node you have a context of property expressions you can parse, so based on the context of the parent node, you have a few options for parsing the child property nodes. For example, the VariableDeclaration has an `id` prop, and an `init` prop. The `id` prop can be a simple name, or it can be an array expression (or an object expression, but I haven't handled that case just yet, only the array expression case). So we might have these examples:

```
const a1 = 123
const a2 = b
const [a3, a4] = c
const { a5, a6 } = d
```

For the array expression, it converts it into two different variable declarations, so it would be:

```
const a3 = c[0]
const a4 = c[1]
const a5 = d.a5
const a6 = d.a6
```

Stuff like that. So that handling is based on the context. Likewise, in the ExpressionStatement context, we assume we have a whole line to ourselves. While in the plain Expression context, we could be nested inside something else. So you might have a ternary/conditional expression as an ExpressionStatement (on a line), or nested in an argument to a CallExpression. That sort of stuff. Or as the result of a variable. Etc.

So what I ended up doing to "solve" these cases is to just duplicate a lot of the logic in multiple different contexts as you'll notice. They have slightly different final result handling, but the bulk of it is the same.

How could I accomplish the following?

1. **Reduce the duplication.** So that there is only ideally one normalizer per node type, or at least the bulk of it is abstracted away somehow.
2. **We can remove the `normalizers` objects**. This is a dynamically constructed object with function handlers for each node type *depending on the context of the parent*. It uses a `node` property for the most part, coming from the parent function scope. Ideally we wouldn't be constructing functions like this on the fly. Instead, there would be a flat list of normalizer functions, independent of context potentially? I dunno if that is possible. But something to remove the scope-dependent implementation like I have.

*Do you even need the `normalizers` objects? Do you need to keep track of the parent context, and have a normalize function for each parent/child context pair? I'm not sure.*

You don't have to rewrite the entire file as it's over 1,000 lines currently and it is probably too much work. But if you could paint the picture on how to specifically refactor it to address these 2 points, that would be wonderful. Thank you.

*Note: what I'm finding is that I haven't handled every combination of contexts (parent/child relationships), so I keep having to add more normalizers to the normalizer map as I encounter them. But I have handled almost every type of expression at least once, so in theory I should not have to extend the code any further. That's sort of what I'm thinking.*

Comment: How is [this branch](https://github.com/lancejpollard/normalize-ast.js/blob/de18f76499a60aabfffab563bb9dd99e7986ae21/index.js) in terms of refactoring (and making more robust)?